# Extract XLSX files from Sublevels in zipped folder with Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I'm working on a project where I need to extract excel files using pentaho data integration (kettle) inside two sublevels of zipped folder, read these files in xlsx at once, to load the database, in the following loads I will only need the files more recent ones like the one from the last day, for example.

[File Directory Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwDOO.jpg)

I tried using Step get file names to bring in the files, but I can't get down to the zipped folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

This step uses Apache Commons VFS.
So for the step access a zip file you need the following syntax: zip://{full path}

For example - zip://C:/Test/server-folder001.zip

From here you can chain steps of Get File Names for each other ZIP files contained, until you reach the last zip which has the XLSX files you require.